# ASP CLASSIC and Procedural programming

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, procedural-programming

Whats your opinion of using this? I recently went to an interview for a graduate job and this is pretty much what they are using. I asked about OOP which I am used to and more updated versions but apparently they are not planning to upgrade any time soon (Small Company).
I reckon I have a good shot of getting this job so I guess I'd like a little bit of advice outside the realms of code issues and your opinion of coding this way / general guidance.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at any of their code ? You cannot avoid OOP concepts in ASP.NET, so if they're coding procedurally I suspect they're using classic ASP. In which case, you may be in for a rough ride - debugging/maintaining someone else's ASP can get ugly. Good luck though.

Comment: Don't call it classic it's confusing enough [tag:asp-classic] is Active Server Pages 3.0 and not ASP.Net. If you want to distinguish between [tag:asp.net] and asp.net mvc use the [tag:asp.net-mvc] tag.

Answer (score 3):

Classic ASP.NET WebForms is still full of Object Oriented Programming concepts that you really can't skirt around (every component on a page is an object w/ methods, etc.) so you should be completely familiar with it.

ASP.NET WebForms has actually come a long way and still has a ton of interesting problems to solve. Personally, I think it's much more of a challenge to write good WebForms code than something like ASP.NET MVC.

Either way, you'll learn a ton which is priceless when getting your first gig after graduating. If nothing else, you'll get hands on experience writing production code and a great glimpse into why so many people have made the leap to MVC (and what the strengths/weaknesses of each paradigm are).

Comment: Hmm, they specifically told me it was top down so I guess it's not ASP.net and it's classic ASP. But yeah true the experience will still be invaluable. Thanks